# The statistics/statistical analysis behind multivariate testing for website

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

I am currently looking for some helpful resource to have better understanding on the data analysis (mathematically) behind the multivariate testing for website design test. Look forward to your suggestions! Thanks

Comment: @whuber, how come no comments to the responder for this "vague question"? It's quite interesting to note that you were prompt in "teaching" [me](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359699/how-to-deal-with-large-number-of-independent-variables?noredirect=1#comment676207_359705)! On the contrary no "thoughtful comments" in here! Why?

Comment: @nilāmbara You seem to conflate "broad" with "vague," but those are different things.  The topic here is clear and the reason for closing is, I hope, equally clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A basic overview](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/multivariate-testing-101-a-scientific-method-of-optimizing-design/) to answer *"what is multivariate testing?"*  It also differentiates between A/B testing and multivariate testing.  I view it as a useful 101-type document.

[A slightly higher-level overview](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/multivariate-testing/) of the mechanics, beginning to step into the mathematics behind the method.  Again, this provides a multivariate vs. A/B comparison.

The underlying mathematics of the method are based in queuing theory, but I will not go into answering that since [the question was answered here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18923/math-behind-multivariate-testing-for-website-optimization).